# js get php variable with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple button calling a js function. There I want use the php var with dynamic names. Any Idea please?

```
<?php 
    $counter = 1;
    ${"fotos" . $counter++} = array(); 
    foreach ($row as $item) {
      ${"fotos" . $counter}[] = $item->img;
    }
 ?>; 
//will generate two vars:
       $fotos  = [img1];
       $fotos1 = [img1,img2];

<button type="button" onClick="verAdjuntos(<?php echo $counter; ?>)" class="btn btn-xs    btn-default"> View</button>
//parameter passed verAdjuntos(1) forxample
```

When id parameter is null, the if condition works fine. But adding id to php var name is the problem...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function verAdjuntos(id){
    if (id == null){
      var fotos  = <?php echo $fotos ?>; //output ok
      alert(JSON.stringify(fotos));
    }else{
      var fotos  = <?php echo  $fotos?> + id; /// how do name $fotos1 here?
      alert(JSON.stringify(fotos));
   };
  }
</script>
```

Doing alert work fine too:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(fotos1));
```

Comment: Problem? What is the problem?

Comment: I _think_ you're getting confused. PHP runs on the server, JS on the client. They can't directly interact. But from the question I can't actually tell if that's what the problem is...

Comment: nope, from server i generated multiple php vars, and from client y get retrieve only names of these vars

Comment: Not convinced. For example `var fotos  = '<?php echo  $fotos'+num+' ?>';` <--- this can't work.

Comment: have you tried to change the function call? like so with additional single quotes: `onclick="varAdjuntos('<?php echo $counter; ?>')"`

Comment: Yes, i tried onclick="varAdjuntos('<?php echo $counter; ?>')" i can retrieve fine this line var fotos  = <?php echo $fotos ?>; my problem is assign id paremeter to var fotos  = <?php echo $fotos1 ?>; for example. If is posible...

Comment: as jon stirling said, this is not possible this way. As PHP runs before JS, you could create a JS-array with PHP and then access your JS array instead of a specific PHP variable. If you put all your fotos in a PHP array `$fotos`, try `var javascriptFotoArray = [<?php echo join(",", $fotos); ?>];`. you then can access your fotos in your `verAdjuntos(id)`-function like `var fotos = javascriptFotoArray[id];`. Disadvantage of this solution is that all your fotos would be visible in sourcecode. how about using AJAX ?

Comment: If you want to create a dynamic var use this: `${"fotos" . $num}`

Comment: Please provide more code to show more information about your  `$counter` and also why you have to use dynamic variables instead of an array! It would also be interesting, if you create multiple buttons, or just one!

Comment: Solved doing with array of arrays from php variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved doing with array of arrays from php variable.

```
<?php 
    $counter = 1;
    $fotos = array(); 
    foreach ($row as $item) {
      $allfotos[$counter] = array($item->img);
      $counter++;
    }
 ?>; 
//will generate two vars:
       $fotos[1]  = [img1];
       $fotos[2]  = [img1,img2];

<button type="button" onClick="verAdjuntos(<?php echo $counter; ?>)" class="btn btn-xs    btn-default"> View</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
function verAdjuntos(id){
    if (id == null){
        var fotos  = <?php echo $allfotos ?>;
        alert(JSON.stringify(fotos));
    }else{   
        <?php
            $js_array = json_encode($allfotos);
            echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
        ?>
        var fotos  = JSON.parse(javascript_array[id]); 
        alert(JSON.stringify(fotos));
    };


}
</script>
```